# Applying lambda row on df with if statement

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two data frames, trying to use entries from `df1` to limit amounts in `df2`, then add them up.  It seems like my code is limiting right, but not adding the amounts up.

**Code:**

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Caps':['25','45','65']})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Amounts':['45','25','65','35','85']})

df1['Capped'] = df1.apply(lambda row: df2['Amounts'].where(
     df2['Amounts'] <= row['Caps'], row['Caps']).sum(), axis=1)
```

**Output:**

```
>>> df1

  Caps      Capped
0   25  2525252525
1   45  4525453545
2   65  4525653565
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First is necessary convert values to integers by [`Series.astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.astype.html):

```
df1['Caps'] = df1['Caps'].astype(int)
df2['Amounts'] = df2['Amounts'].astype(int)
df1['Capped'] = df1.apply(lambda row: df2['Amounts'].where(
                   df2['Amounts'] <= row['Caps'], row['Caps']).sum(), axis=1)

print (df1)
   Caps  Capped
0    25     125
1    45     195
2    65     235
```

For improve performance is possible use [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) with broadcasting:

```
df1['Caps'] = df1['Caps'].astype(int)
df2['Amounts'] = df2['Amounts'].astype(int)

am = df2['Amounts'].to_numpy()
ca = df1['Caps'].to_numpy()
#pandas below 0.24
#am = df2['Amounts'].values
#ca = df1['Caps'].values
df1['Capped'] = np.where(am <= ca[:, None], am[None, :], ca[:, None]).sum(axis=1)
print (df1)
   Caps  Capped
0    25     125
1    45     195
2    65     235
```

Comment: Thanks, I agree that this solves the issue for this example I created.  But I still have an error on my original code.

After investigating the numbers I'm capping ('df2' from example above), I see that they are type decimal.Decimal.  When changing to astype(float), it solves my issue.  Thanks again.